# TableLayout removeAllViews not removing children

Tags: java, android, debugging, tablelayout

In my refresh method I clear the TableRow elements to make room for the new button array and also try to clear the TableLayout to make room for the freshly updated TableRows, but I keep getting an error saying TableLayout isn't cleared. It would appear table.remveAllViews(); isn't working.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.tilegame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener 
{
    TableLayout table;
    Button buttons[];
    int count = 0;
    int btnSize = 0;
    TableRow row;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSize = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.box_size);
        table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);      
        buttons = new Button[9];
        row = new TableRow(this);

        for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            if(x < 8)
            {
                Button btn = createButton(btnSize, false, x+1);
                buttons[x] = btn;
            }
            else if(x == 8)
            {
                Button btn = createButton(btnSize, true, x+1);
                buttons[x] = btn;
            }
        }
        randomizeArray(buttons);
        table.removeAllViews();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                row.addView(buttons[count]);
                count++;
            }
            table.addView(row, x);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case 0:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 1:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 2:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 3:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 4:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 5:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 6:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;

            case 7:
                swap(buttons, v.getId());
                refresh();
                break;
        }
    }

    public Button createButton(int size, boolean blank, int id)
    {
        Button btn = new Button(this);

        LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(size, size);
        buttonParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
        btn.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        btn.setId(id);
        btn.setText(""+btn.getId());
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(blank == false)
        {
            btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
        else
        {
            btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return btn;
    }

    public void randomizeArray(Button[] array)
    {
        List<Button> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Button i : array)
        {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        for(int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
        {
            array[x] = list.get(x);
        }
    }

    public void refresh()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            View child = table.getChildAt(x);
            if(child instanceof TableRow)
            {
                ((ViewGroup) child).removeAllViews();
            }
        }
        table.removeAllViews();
        count = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                row.addView(buttons[count]);
                count++;
            }
            table.addView(row, x);
        }
    }

    public void swap(Button btns[], int id)
    {
        int posClick = 0;
        int posBlank = 0;
        Button temp1 = new Button(this);
        Button temp2 = new Button(this);

        for(int x = 0; x < btns.length; x++)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(btns[x].getText().toString()) == id)
            {
                posClick = x;
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < btns.length; x++)
        {
            if(Integer.parseInt(btns[x].getText().toString()) == 9)
            {
                posBlank = x;
            }
        }
        switch(posClick)
        {
            case 0:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 3)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                if(posBlank == 0 || posBlank == 2 || posBlank == 4)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 5)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(posBlank == 0 || posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 6)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if(posBlank == 1 || posBlank == 3 || posBlank == 5 || posBlank == 7)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if(posBlank == 2 || posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 8)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                if(posBlank == 3 || posBlank == 7)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if(posBlank == 4 || posBlank == 6 || posBlank == 8)
                {
                    temp1 = btns[posClick];
                    temp2 = btns[posBlank];
                    btns[posBlank] = temp1;
                    btns[posClick] = temp2;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/outside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tilegame.MainActivity" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#38c0f4"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_1"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_1">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_2"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_2">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_3"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_3">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_4"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_5"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_6"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="@string/num_6" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/row3">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_7"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_7">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/num_8"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                android:text="@string/num_8">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/blank"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/box_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/box_size"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="5dip">
            </Button>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Log Cat (meow):

```
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284): Process: com.example.tilegame, PID: 11284
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3771)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3624)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3569)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at com.example.tilegame.MainActivity.refresh(MainActivity.java:167)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at com.example.tilegame.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:107)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4640)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19421)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
10-04 03:07:10.187: E/AndroidRuntime(11284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which line of your code is com.example.tilegame.MainActivity.refresh(MainActivity.java:167)

Comment: @Mike In the refresh() method it is 'table.addView(row, x);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your oncreate you are doing

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            row.addView(buttons[count]);
            count++;
        }
        table.addView(row, x);
    }
```

But your refresh code has:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            row.addView(buttons[count]);
            count++;
        }
        table.addView(row, x);
    }
```

Since you are not creating a local row object in that case, you are attempting to add your class row variable multiple times to the table in the refresh. It may be best to remove your TableRow row; from your class since you are using the same naming convention for your method variables and are not using the class scoped `row` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much! Such a simple fix.. I need more coffee.